# Finding [T] β β for β the standard basis for R3

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let α = {(1,1,1),(1,1,0),(1,0,0)} be a basis for R3. Let T satisfy T{(1,1,1)} = (2,2,2) , T{(1,1,0)} = (3,3,0), and T{(1,0,0)} = (-1,0,0)

Find [T]<sub>β</sub> <sup>β</sup> for β the standard basis of R3

I've had trouble understanding the answer to this problem as the textbook gave:

\begin{Bmatrix} 
      -1 & 4 & -1\\ 
      0 & 3 & -1\\ 
      0 & 0 & 2\\
   \end{Bmatrix}

Could please explain to me what  [T]β β means in this context and how to go about calculating it

Comment: What does the book say "standard basis" means? How does the book define the matrix of a linear transformation with respect to given bases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find $[T]_\beta$, we need to check how $T$ "acts" on each of the vectors in the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3.$

So, by the linearity of $T$:

$T(1,0,0)=(-1,0,0)=-1(1,0,0)+0(0,1,0)+0(0,0,1)$

$T(0,1,0)=T(1,1,0)-T(1,0,0)=(3,3,0)-(-1,0,0)=(4,3,0)=4(1,0,0)+3(0,1,0)+0(0,0,1)$

$T(0,0,1)=T(1,1,1)-T(1,1,0)=(2,2,2)-(3,3,0)=(-1,-1,0)=-1(1,0,0)-1(0,1,0)+2(0,0,1)$

Placing the the coordinates we got in the columns of a matrix:

$$[T]_\beta=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 4 &-1 \\0 & 3 & -1\\0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$